# My statement inside else if under line 41 to 51 is not being executed

Tags: c

I am writing a program using c that stimulates a game called rock, paper, and scissors.

The rest of the script works perfectly but the else if statement in line 41-51 is not being excuted.

```
int user;
int robot;

printf ("Rock, Paper, and Scissors \n\n");

printf("Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissors = 3\n\n");

printf("User's move: ");
scanf("%d", &user);
printf("Robot's move: ");
scanf("%d", &robot);

if(user == 1|| robot == 2)
{
    printf("Robot wins by choosing Paper!");
}
else if(user == 2 || robot == 1)
{
 printf("User wins by choosing Paper!");
}
else if (user == 2 || robot == 3)
{
    printf("Robot wins by choosing Scissors! ");
}
else if (user == 3 || robot == 2)
{
    printf("User wins by choosing Scissors!");
}
else if (user == 3 || robot == 1)
{
    printf("Robot wins by choosing Rock!");
}
else if (user == 1 || robot == 3)
{
    printf("User wins by choosing Rock!");
}
else if (user == 1 || robot == 1)
{
    printf("It's a tie!");
}
else if (user == 2 || robot == 2)
{
    printf("It's a tie!");
}
else if (user == 3 || robot == 3)
{
    printf("It's a tie!");
} }
```

It should print the message "its a tie" whenever I input the same number in users input but it wasn't executing.

Comment: Every single `||` is wrong and should be replaced by `&&`.

Comment: There is no line number, you could write that if block separately which is not working.
Also, it shouldn't be `||` it should be `&&`

Comment: That very incomplete code snippet does not even have 51 lines.

Answer (score 3):

`||` means "or". E.g. `user == 1 || robot == 2` is checking to see if either `user == 1` *or* `robot == 2`. Either of those will result in `printf("Robot wins by choosing Paper!");` being executed.

Once you get to the tie conditions, every possibility (given the user entering 1, 2, or 3) has occurred. None of the tie messages *can* be printed.

If you use `&&` for "and" your code will behave the way you expect as you will know that *both* conditions are true.

Also note, that for a tie condition, you could write either:

```
else if (user == robot) {
    ...
}
```

Or assuming you've validated that `user` and `robot` are both either 1, 2, or 3, and you've covered all other possible combinations, simply:

```
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting Boolean logic right can be tough at the beginning.
You could write the code without using explicit boolean symbols (or tons of curly braces):

```
if( user == robot)
    printf("It's a tie!");
else if(user == 1)
    if( robot == 2)
        printf("Robot wins by choosing Paper!");
    else
        printf("User wins by choosing Rock!");
else if(user == 2)
    if(robot == 1)
        printf("User wins by choosing Paper!");
    else
        printf("Robot wins by choosing Scissors! ");
else if(user == 3)
    if(robot == 2)
        printf("User wins by choosing Scissors!");
    else
        printf("Robot wins by choosing Rock!");
```

---

**EDIT:**
With the first of the DVs recorded, I accept the challenge...

Here is Sheldon Cooper's "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock". Maybe someone will take the time to write the `&&` and `||` version to compare. I don't know what that might look like; it'd be interesting to see.
(This uses `rand()` to generate the opponent's moves.)

```
char *dr = "DRAW\n\n";

char *sp = "scissors cuts paper";
char *pr = "paper covers rock";
char *rl = "rock crushes lizard";
char *ln = "lizard poisons Spock";
char *ns = "Spock smashes scissors";
char *sl = "scissors decapitates lizard";
char *lp = "lizard eats paper";
char *pn = "paper disproves Spock";
char *nr = "Spock vaporizes rock";
char *rs = "rock crushes scissors";

char *tbl[][6] = {
    { dr, pr, rs, rl, nr, " lwwl", },
    { pr, dr, sp, lp, pn, "w llw", },
    { rs, sp, dr, sl, ns, "lw wl", },
    { rl, lp, sl, dr, ln, "lwl w", },
    { nr, pn, ns, ln, dr, "wlwl ", },
};

void evaluate( int usr, int cpu ) {
    char *elems[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "nimoy(spock)" };
    printf ( "\nYou: %-14s - PC: %-14s - %s", elems[ usr ], elems[ cpu ], tbl[usr][cpu] );
    if( usr != cpu )
        printf( " - %s\n\n", tbl[usr][5][cpu] == 'w' ? "WIN!!" : "lose..." );
}

void oneRound() {
    char *choices = "rpslnRPSLN";
    char buf[32];

    printf( "choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): " );
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
    char *cp = strchr( choices, buf[0] );
    if( cp == NULL )
        puts( "bad entry" );
    else
        evaluate( ( cp - choices ) % 5, rand() % 5 );
}

int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );
    for( ;; )
        oneRound();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT2:**
There are many ways to skin those cats. Here's RPS with NO explicit boolean operations and only 3 pairs of curly braces inside the single function block.

```
/* The usual headers */
int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );

    char *elems[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
    char *choices = "rpsRPS";
    char buf[32];

    for( ;; ) {
        printf( "choose rock paper scissors: " );
        fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
        char *cp = strchr( choices, buf[0] );
        if( cp == NULL ) { puts( "bad entry" ); continue; }
        int usr = ( cp - choices ) % 3;
        int cpu = rand() % 3;
        printf ( "You chose: %s - PC chose: %s - ", elems[ usr ], elems[ cpu ] );

        if( usr == cpu )
            puts( "Draw" );
        else
            puts( ( usr + 1 ) %3 == cpu ? "Lose" : "Win" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT3: (final)**
In the never ending struggle to conserve curly braces, there's also this that uses a hash function to 'decode' each of the 3x3 combinations, printing results similar to the OP's output. We must all do all we can to prevent (forestall) a global shortage of curly braces!

```
int main() {
    char *strs[] = {
        "It's a tie",
        "Robot wins by choosing Paper",
        "User wins by choosing Rock",
        "User wins by choosing Paper",
        "", // not used
        "Robot wins by choosing Scissors",
        "Robot wins by choosing Rock",
        "User wins by choosing Scissors",
    };

    char *elems[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors", };

    for( int usr = 0; usr < 3; usr++ )
        for( int rbt = 0; rbt < 3; rbt++ )
            printf( "u:%-9s  r:%-9s  == %s\n",
                elems[usr],
                elems[rbt],
                strs[ !!(usr^rbt) * (((usr<<2)+rbt)-usr)&7 ] );

    return 0;
}
```